# In Objective-C, how to make @property's accessible to other classes?

Tags: objective-c, properties, parent

**The original question remains below this update:**

So further research indicates that my

> "...missing setter or instance variable"

log messages are due to an unhinged `.xib`.

I originally thought that might be the case which is why I went through the process of re-connecting the outlets and properties in the graphic interface builder, but that seems to have been insufficient to repair the connections.

I restored the outlets as properties rather than iVars and reconnected again, still to no avail. So I'm in the process of remaking the .xib's from scratch. Stay tuned for the results.

**Original question follows:**

Having declared and synthesized properties in parent and sheet classes, and attempted therein to access the properties by their respective class.property names, Xcode rejects the code.

I posted a similar question recently and deleted it after being told there was not enough info to make a response, so I include here below a mini-app which shows how the relevant setup was in the real app of over 2000 lines of Objective-C, which built and ran properly before I attempted to add the Parent / Sheet properties feature.

I've indicated the compiler error messages with a prefix of `////`. When I comment out the erroneous lines, the app with its `.xib`'s builds and runs, dysfunctionally of course.

ParentClass.h

```
// ParentClass stuff belongs in the original main window controller
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ParentClass : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField * messageTextField;
    IBOutlet NSButton    * proceedButton;
}
@property (assign)  IBOutlet  NSWindow * window;
@property (strong)  NSMutableString * parentPropInfo;
- (IBAction) awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction) doCreate:(id)sender;
@end
```

ParentClass.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "ParentDelegate.h"
#import "ParentClass.h"
#import "SheetClass.h"
@implementation ParentClass
ParentDelegate     * MyDelegate;  // only confirms termination requests
NSWindowController * SheetController;
@synthesize parentPropInfo;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib  {
    MyDelegate = [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    MyDelegate.ParentController = self;   // BTW, this property assignment works!
    SheetController = [[SheetClass alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"SheetClass"];
    messageTextField.stringValue = @"Click Proceed button";
}
- (IBAction)doProceed*emphasized text*:(id)sender  {
    parentPropInfo = @"Hello!".mutableCopy;   // to be read by the sheet
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:SheetController.window];
    // Sheet is active now until it issues stopModal, then:

    messageTextField.stringValue = SheetController.sheetPropInfo;   // set by the sheet
////above gets ERROR "Property sheetPropInfo not found on object of type 'NSWindowController *'"

    messageTextField.stringValue = SheetController.window.sheetPropInfo;
////above gets ERROR "Property sheetPropInfo not found on object of type 'NSWindow *'"

    [NSApp endSheet: SheetController.window];
    [SheetController.window orderOut:self];
}
@end
```

SheetClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "ParentClass.h"
@interface SheetClass : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField * propTextField;
    IBOutlet NSButton    * cancelButton;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow * window;
@property   NSMutableString * sheetPropInfo;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction)doCancel:(id)sender;
@end
```

SheetClass.m

```
#import "SheetClass.h"
#import "ParentClass.h"
@implementation SheetClass
@synthesize sheetPropInfo;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib  {

    propTextField.stringValue = self.window.sheetParent.parentPropInfo;  // set by the parent
////above gets ERROR "Property parentPropInfo not found on object of type 'NSWindow *'"

    sheetPropInfo = @"Goodbye!".mutableCopy;  // to be read by the parent
}
- (IBAction)doCancel:(id)sender  {
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
@end
```

I can find nothing in Apple documentation or extensive (three weeks now!) online search to offer any insight as to my abysmal ignorance. I apologize for the overwhelming batch of code needed to illustrate my problem! Where shall I obtain the information I need?

Comment: This code is a big mess, so there are several errors. Most of them are due to wrong types. For example, you are trying to access `sheetPropInfo` type on a property of type `NSWindowController`. You seem to be confused with Objective-C strong type system. In the bottom one, you are accessing `sheetParent` property on a `NSWindow`, as far as I can see. Both are not there. Try type casting it to correct type.

Comment: And your outlets should be declared as properties in the .h, not as private ivars. And `@synthesize` hasn't needed in many years. And worst, your `MyDelegate` and `SheetController` are declared as global variables, not instance variables.

Comment: It's also a really, really bad design to attempt to have a circular dependency between `SheetClass` and `ParentClass`.

Comment: @Legoless - sheetParent is a property of an NSWindow when such window is a sheet, and it points to the sheet's parent widow. My corrected code (when it's running well will show this as correctly done).
You were right about my not declaring the sheetPropInfo container as type SheetClass.

Comment: @rmaddy Please explain what you mean by 'circular dependency'. Would it be what I'd call 'bi-directional communication' where the participants can populate each other's properties? Or does it refer to the necessity for the sheet user to click the Cancel button (calling endModal) before the sheet is dismissed? What other? Thanks.

Comment: My original point was about have both classes have properties of each other but now that I look at your .h files again, this isn't actually the case. Your `ParentClass.h` has `@class SheetClass;` but that line isn't actually needed.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right about that `@class SheetClass` line being unnecessary and I actually removed it sometime after posting the question. Maybe I should have edited the question also. I will now. You are very sharp observer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are perfectly clear. Just read them and think about them. Let's just take the first one. You are saying:

```
messageTextField.stringValue = SheetController.sheetPropInfo;
```

...and getting this response from the compiler:

```
// Property sheetPropInfo not found on object of type 'NSWindowController *'
```

Well, think about the expression `SheetController.sheetPropInfo` and why the compiler cannot make sense of it. You have declared SheetController as follows:

```
NSWindowController * SheetController;
```

So that is all the compiler knows: SheetController is an NSWindowController. Well, sure enough, just as the compiler says, `sheetPropInfo` *is not a property of NSWindowController.* It is a property of SheetClass (which is not the same as NSWindowController; it is a subclass of NSWindowController).

If you know that SheetController is in fact a SheetClass instance, you need to tell the compiler that fact. You must either declare SheetController as a SheetClass or cast it down from an NSWindowController to a SheetClass.

Comment: Also please stop using capital letters for variable names. Capital letters are for class names, not instance names.